# Expression syntax error issue

Tags: c

I was writing a simple code to change from lowercase to uppercase but its showing expression syntax error on a line 12 in the if() statement. The code runs fine without equality sign but does not work with equality. Any help to rectify it is appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
char s[]="Computer";
int i;
clrscr();
for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
  {
   if (s[i] > = 'a' && s[i] < = 'z')
   s[i]+='A'-'a';
  }
puts(s); 
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, as "too much space" is causing this syntax error, there are several occurences of "too little space" in terms of readability/style in your code. Just suggest you look at some well-established C code and adapt some stylistic best practices.

Comment: some of them are: Have spaces around any operator, have a space after `#include`, after `;` and after `,`, decide for a consistent indentation scheme and have a conditional statement *either* in one line or use a *block*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `> =` is not valid syntax because of the space between `>` and `=`. Delete the space :

```
if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error you are getting is due to the space between `>` and `=` operators. Likewise for `<` and `=`. Also, this would be a better version of your code:

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "Computer";
    size_t i, len = strlen(s);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
            s[i] -= 32;
    }

    puts(s); 
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please look your code in `if(s[i] > = 'a' && s[i] < = 'z')`
as `if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')`

Comment: No need to give the same answer *20 minutes later* and without comprehensible explanation.